# Cloning and renaming form elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am looking for an effective way to either clone/rename or re-create address fields to offer ability to submit multiple addresses on the same page. So with form example like this:

```
<div id="addresses">
  <div class="address">
    <input type="text" name="address[0].street">
    <input type="text" name="address[0].city">
    <input type="text" name="address[0].zip">
    <input type="text" name="address[0].state">
  </div>
</div>
<a href="" id="add_address">Add address form</a>
```

From what I can understand there are two options to do that:

1. Recreate the form field by field and increment the index which is kind of verbose:

   ```
   var index = $(".address").length;

   $('<`input`>').attr({
   name: 'address[' + index + '].street',
   type: 'text'
   }).appendTo(...);

   $('<`input`>').attr({
   name: 'address[' + index + '].city',
   type: 'text'
   }).appendTo(...);

   $('<`input`>').attr({
   name: 'address[' + index + '].zip',
   type: 'text'
   }).appendTo(...);

   $('<`input`>').attr({
   name: 'address[' + index + '].state',
   type: 'text'
   }).appendTo(...);
   ```
2. Clone Existing layer and replace the name in the clone:

   ```
   $("div.address").clone().appendTo($("#addresses"));
   ```

Which one do you recommend using in terms of being more efficient and if its #2 can you please suggest how I would go about search and replacing all occurrences of [0] with [1] ([n]). Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In theory, the simplest way would be to clone then change name:

```
var newaddress= $("#addresses div.address").eq(0).clone();
newaddress.find('input').each(function() {
    this.name= this.name.replace('[0]', '['+i+']');
});
$('#addresses').append(newaddress);
```

However:

a. jQuery's `clone()` is a really nasty piece of work. On IE, it serialises the nodes to HTML, processes the HTML string with regex (!) to remove its bodge-job internal ID attributes and then asks the browser to re-parse it. This is one of my least favourite parts of jQuery: it's highly error-prone, loses some information, and is slow (not that speed matters for the quite small job you seem to be doing here).

The browser's native `cloneNode(true)` method is much better, but you can't really use it if you're doing jQuery stuff because it will copy jQuery's internal ids, potentially confusing its scripting. Ugh. What a mess.

b. When you change an input's name, whether that's by `input.name` as here or using `attr()` as in your example, there are issues in IE<=7.

In particular, though it will submit the inputs with the correct control name, they won't be indexed under the right name in the `form.elements` HTMLCollection (or on `form` itself, though you shouldn't use that anyway). This isn't necessarily a problem if you are selecting inputs based on IDs or jQuery selectors rather than the old-school HTMLCollection interface. Worse is that radio buttons, if you use any, won't be properly name-grouped.

If this is a concern for you I'm afraid using `innerHTML`/`html()` to create the div, as in pst's answer, is your only option. (You can always combine the two, creating using HTML then changing the other attributes and text content using `text()`, `attr()`, `val()` etc. to avoid the usual HTML-escaping problems when you go around sticking text strings into HTML.)

Comment: That is perfect! thank you for explanation of the inner workings of clone as well a reminder on issues with changing input's name in IE.

Answer (score 4):

It's much less verbose if you write it sanely :-) I would likely just use clone and append. *However*, you'll get duplicate names. This isn't a big deal if your back-end can correctly handle "address[].street", but it may not and in such a case you'd need to cleanup after the clone. Thus I'd recommend "hiding it in a tidy builder function".

```
function createAddress (index) {
  return jQuery(replace('\
    <div class="address">\
      <input type="text" name="address[{i}].street">\
      <input type="text" name="address[{i}].city">\
      <input type="text" name="address[{i}].zip">\
      <input type="text" name="address[{i}].state">\
    </div>\
    ', {i: index}))
}
```

Where replace is some tidy function which understands a simple interpolation mapping. I prefer to "keep markup in something that looks like markup".

Worrying about performance here is likely not warranted.

Comment: That is certainly a more sane way of doing it :) The reason I am leaning toward clone method because state is actually a select field populated with a list of states, so cloning seem to be easier. Could I use it here in a similar way and get html() of my cloned div and then replace index using regex maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I belive i am going through the same thing and found some great source that goes like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function trimNums(stringToTrim)
    {
        return stringToTrim.replace(/\d+$/,"");
    }
    function dupForm(divId, divClass, btnAdd, btnRm)
    {
    //alert(divId+'   '+divClass);
        var num     = $(divClass).length;
        var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);
        var i;
        var newElem = $('#' + divId + num).clone().attr('id', divId + newNum).fadeIn('slow');
        for (i=0; i < newElem.children().length; i++)
        {
            var attrId = trimNums(newElem.children(':eq('+i+')').attr('id'));
            var attrName = trimNums(newElem.children(':eq('+i+')').attr('name'));
            newElem.children(':eq('+i+')').attr('id', attrId + newNum).val('');
        }
        $('#' + divId + num).after(newElem);
        $('#' + btnRm).attr('disabled','');
        if (newNum == 15)
            $('#' + btnAdd).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    function rmForm(divId, divClass, btnAdd, btnRm)
    {
        var num = $(divClass).length;
        $('#' + divId + num).remove();
        $('#' + btnAdd).attr('disabled','');
        if (num-1 == 1)
            $('#' + btnRm).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
</script>
```

and the html code is:

```
<form id="myForm" action="testingForm.php" method="post">
<div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
    Part #: <input name="part[]" type="text" id="part1" size="10" maxlength="15" />
    Description: <input name="description[]" type="text" id="description1" size="30" maxlength="50" />
    Qty: <input name="quantity[]" type="text" id="quantity1" size="5" maxlength="5" />
```

....