# Saving arrays with key/value pairs

Tags: php, laravel-5

Unable to save arrays with the correct key based on how many inputs the user selects.

I have tried the following:

I've tried to json encode some elements, but to no avail.

Here's the html:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Block Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name_of_blocks[]" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>No of units in the block</label>
            <input type="number" name="no_units[]" class="form-control" id="blockNo">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>Number of floors</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="no_of_floors[]">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>Does this block have a lift?</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="lift[]">
                <option>Please Select</option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label>What facilities does this block have?</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="fob"> Fob Entry</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="gate_entry"> Gate Entry</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="key"> Key Entry</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="finger"> Fingerprint Entry</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="Code Entry"> Code Entry</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="mailbox"> Mailbox Area</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="bar"> Bar</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="bike_storage"> Bike Storage</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="car_park"> Secure Car Parking</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="off_road"> Off-road Parking</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="visitor_parking"> Visitor Parking</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="concierge"> Concierge</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="gym"> Gym</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="pool"> Swimming Pool </li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="snooker"> Snooker/Pool Table</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="cafe"> Cafe</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="maintenance"> Maintenance Service</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="various"> Various businesses/commercial outlets</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Heres what I have in my controller, but this either doesn't save correctly or saves one row if there's two and doesn't save the correct info:

```
$data = $request->all();
$count = $data['number_of_blocks'];
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    $fac = array_values($request->facilities);
    $facil = json_encode($fac);

    $blok = new Blocks;
    $blok->block_id = $block->id;
    $blok->name_of_blocks = array_key_exists($i, $data['name_of_blocks']) ? $data['name_of_blocks'][$i] : null;
    $blok->no_units = array_key_exists($i, $data['no_units']) ? $data['no_units'][$i] : null;
    $blok->no_of_floors = array_key_exists($i, $data['no_of_floors']) ? $data['no_of_floors'][$i] : null;
    $blok->lift = array_key_exists($i, $data['lift']) ? $data['lift'][$i] : null;
    $blok->facilities = array_key_exists($i, $facil) ? $facil[$i] : null;
    $blok->save();
}
```

I do have some clone script to clone the amount of form fields based on how many the user wants, so this could also be a problem, but I'm not sure what or where:

```
$("#continue").click(function () {
    $("#first").hide();
    $("#second").show();

    var blocks = $("#noBlocks").val();
    var name = $("#blockName").val();
    $(".clone").hide();
    var select = parseInt(blocks, 10);
    var $clone = $('.clone').html();
    var html = '';
    while (select > 0) {
        html += $clone;
        select--;
    }

    $("#area").empty().html(html);

    $("#bno").html(blocks);
    $("#bn").html(name);
});
```

Basically if the user selects 2 then I want the code to save two rows and the facilities to be json encoded for each row, and match what the user selects. Any help advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: It won’t work this way. Checkboxes only become part of the form submission data set, if they are checked - so with the field name `facilities[]`, you will not be able to determine which “row” a value belongs to. You need to specify the index upfront to not lose that association. `facilities[0][]` for the first row, `facilities[1][]`, etc. So you will need to modify your cloning part to update those field names.

Comment: OK, with jQuery not been my strong point, how would achieve this?

Comment: anyone care to help me on the jQuery thing and also how i can get it to save correctly?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649798/cloning-and-renaming-form-elements-with-jquery for starters.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look.